# Error when opening interactive ssh shell from python

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, popen, fabric

I am trying to open an interactive ssh shell through fabric.

Requirements:

- Use fabrics hosts in the connection string to remote
- Open fully interactive shell in current terminal
- Works on osx and ubuntu
- No need for data transfer between fabric/python and remote. So fabric task can end in background.

So far:

fabfile.py:

```
def test_ssh():
    from subprocess import Popen
    Popen('ssh user@1.2.3.4 -i "bla.pem"', shell=True)
```

In terminal:

```
localprompt$ fab test_ssh
localprompt$ tcsetattr: Input/output error

[remote ubuntu welcome here]

remoteprompt$ |
```

Then if I try to input a command on the remote prompt it is executed locally and I drop back to the local prompt.
Does anyone know a solution?

Note: I am aware of fabrics `open_shell`, but this does not work for me since the stdout lags behind, rendering this unusable.

Comment: Why do you want to open an ssh shell with fabric? Why not just run your commands as a fabric task?

Comment: The code above is not using fabric at all. Popen is a local command. I think it makes no sense to execute it in a fabric task.

Comment: Well, normally I do stuff via fabric but some things just require an interactive shell. I want to do this with fabric because right now I have about 20+ sh scripts to connect to my various servers and it is starting to annoy me to keep the connection strings in sync. Fabric would be the appropriate tool to do just that because it already has all connection strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight modification does the trick:

```
def test_ssh():
    from subprocess import call
    call('ssh user@1.2.3.4 -i "bla.pem"', shell=True)
```

As the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997387/perls-backticks-system-giving-tcsetattr-input-output-error) suggests the error suggests the error comes from the inability of ssh to connect to the stdin/out of a process in the background.

With `call` the fabric task does not end in the background, but I am fine with that as long as as it is not interfering with my stdin/out.